# Python terminal Freeze but don't throw error

Tags: python

can someone help me in working with python and i found a bug where the python just Freeze and but not crashing nor throw error
It's just Freeze.

It worked fine for a while but when it's been running for like 1-2 hours it freezed

i try to add print("something") to see if the loop still working but it's not printing.

can someone help me
please help me i don't know how to fix this

Im using the newest python

```
import datetime
import os
import sys
import time
import dw2


class Watcher(object):
    file = None
    running = True
    refresh_delay_secs = 1

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, watch_file, call_func_on_change=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self._cached_stamp = 0
        self.filename = watch_file
        self.file = watch_file
        self.call_func_on_change = call_func_on_change
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    # Look for changes

    def look(self):
        stamp = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
        if stamp != self._cached_stamp:
            self._cached_stamp = stamp
            # File has changed, so do something...
            # print('Updated..')

            
            if self.call_func_on_change is not None:
                self.call_func_on_change(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            return "Updated"
        else:
            #print("Not Updated")
            return "Not Updated"

    # Keep watching in a loop

    def watch(self):
        try:
            # Look for changes
            time.sleep(self.refresh_delay_secs)
            result=self.look()
            if result.__eq__("Updated"):
                dw2.dwc(self.file)
            print(result)
            #if datetime.datetime.now() >= (now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)):
                #self.restart()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\nDone')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        except:
            print('Unhandled error: %s' % sys.exc_info()[0])


    def restart(self):
        os.system('cls')
        os.execv(sys.executable,  ['python'] + sys.argv)

watch_file = 'status.txt'

watcher = Watcher(watch_file)  
# simple
# also call custom action function
watcher = Watcher(watch_file)

while watcher.running :
    try :
        watcher.watch()  
    #start the watch going
    except:
        restart()
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any circumstance where `watcher.running` isn't `True`, so there's an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah i was planning to run this for infinite Times it run normal for a while but when it's running for like 1-2 
hour  it' just freeze

Answer (score 0):

Write at the end of your code , at the exception in the while : sys.exc_info()